# url rewrite using php and .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this question is Basic but important. i need to rewrite php url using .htaccess . e.x one : i have many file with `.php` extension . e.x two : i need seo url friendly with name and `html` extension.

example 1 :

```
http://mydomain.com/editname.php
http://mydomain.com/location.php
.....
```

I need to rewrite all to  :

```
http://mydomain.com/editname/
http://mydomain.com/location/
```

example 2 :

```
http://mydomain.com/name.php?id=1
http://mydomain.com/state.php?id=1
```

rewrite to : ( john & bsw is really name and inserted to mysql)

```
http://mydomain.com/name/1/john.html
http://mydomain.com/state/1/bsw.html
```

**NOTE** : If non of this, redirect to 404 not found page.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect simple folders to PHP files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/])/$ /$1.php [L]
```

And then do redirect your SEO friendly URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/])/([0-9]+)/([^/])\.html$ /$1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

The `RewriteCond` lines check to make sure the request isn't already a valid file.